# Using Catel.Extensions.Prism and RequestNavigate with navigation parameters

Tags: prism, catel

I am just getting started with Catel and attempting to follow the instructions from Catel documentation regarding [Catel.Extensions.Prism](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel.Extensions.Prism) and specifically utilizing the regions functionality of Prism.

I have a demo application to change the view (from ViewA to ViewB)and this works using the RegionManager.RequestNavigate method.  The view changes as expected.
But when I want to pass a parameter using NavigationParameters as a third parameter to the RequestNavigate method.  The view changes as expected, but the INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo method never gets called on the second viewModel( BViewModel).  As such I cannot extract the parameters for use in the second viewModel.

```
        NavigationParameters parameters = new NavigationParameters();
        parameters.Add("Id", document.Id);

        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, new Uri("BView" + parameters, UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there something I am missing to get this to work?  I have looked at Prism [examples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/View-Switching%20Navigation_Desktop) and I believe I am doing everything as in the example.

I have looked into the InterestedIn and MessageMediator, but the second viewModel does not exist when the property on the first viewModel is changed, before the RequestNavigate method is called to switch the view.

I am using Catel 4.4.0 and Prism 6.1.

Comment: There are `RequestNavigate` overloads that accept the navigation parameters directly, like `void RequestNavigate(string regionName, string target, NavigationParameters navigationParameters)`. Have you tried that one, too?

Answer (score 0):

The prism extension doesn't implement the OnNavigatedTo on the view model (yet).